# Unity IOS Load AudioClip from local

Tags: ios, audio, unity-game-engine, resources

I use this code for iOS path:

```
public static string GetiPhoneDocumentsPath () 
    { 

        string path = Application.dataPath.Substring (0, Application.dataPath.Length - 5); 
        path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('/'));  
        return path + "/Documents"; 

    }
```

Documents folder include many .wav files. I want to play this audioClips.

I try this code:

```
string filepath = Path.Combine(GetiPhoneDocumentsPath(),SongName);
AudioClip my = (AudioClip)Resources.Load(filepath, typeof(AudioClip));
audio.clip = my;
audio.Play();
```

but didn't work :(

How can I do???

Comment: the music didn't play.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: AudioClip my = (AudioClip)Resources.Load(filepath, typeof(AudioClip));

This code didn't work.
Return null.